# Thonny IDE, micropython I2c memory operations- readfrom_mem, writeto_mem- returning 0x00 from NAK registers

Tags: i2c, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, thonny

I am trying to design a code where I can determine which registers exist since they can generally be anywhere from 0x00 to 0xFF. Currently using i2c module defined in micropython and also using pico interpreter for the software in Thonny. I just realized that commands readfrom_mem and writeto_mem doesn't really care for ack or nak. Using logic analyzer, I see that it goes through the protocol correctly and doesn't do anything if register puts a nak, but it doesn't return any error and reads back 0x00 on non-existing registers when it clearly just received a nak. I don't understand why it's reading back any values at all. I want to see if anyone has experience in this or if it's even possible for me to write something that distinguishes valid registers from 0-255 possible registers. Any input would be appreciated, thank you.

I tried pretty much almost all the operations possible under I2C class in here https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/machine.I2C.html, but can't seem to utilize any of them to find a solution to my problem.